# I trying to get all user with same ip from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find all user having same ip in database

and i tried few ways.

Now i am trying this but its only giving me one user

here is my short example of php code:

```
<?php
    $CheckQuery = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 
        "SELECT * FROM  `logedfeeds` 
        WHERE ip='127.0.0.1' 
        GROUP BY user_id 
        ORDER BY  `id`
        DESC LIMIT 1000000");
    //create table
    $step1 = '<center><table border="1"><tr><td><b>UserID</b></td></tr>';       
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery)){
        $userip = $row['user_id'];
        $step2 = '<tr><td>' . $userip . '</td></tr>';

    }
    echo "$step1 $step2 </table></center>";
?>
```

I am trying this code but not seems to work.

Comment: Your loop is only returning the last record because `$step2` is overwritten on each iteration. Try `$step2 .= '<tr><td>' . $userip . '</td></tr>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your `$step2` variable

change your code so it becomes

```
<?php
    $CheckQuery = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 
    "SELECT * FROM  `logedfeeds` 
    WHERE ip='127.0.0.1' 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY  `id`
    DESC LIMIT 1000000");
    //create table
    $step1 = '<center><table border="1"><tr><td><b>UserID</b></td></tr>';   
    $step2 = '';    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery)){
        $userip = $row['user_id'];
        $step2 .= '<tr><td>' . $userip . '</td></tr>';

    }
    echo "$step1 $step2 </table></center>";
?>
```

You first declare the `$step2` variable outside your while loop and keep concatenating it then you echo it outside the loop.

Comment: Selecting my answer as the correct one if it helped you would be helpful to me! @JituSingh

Comment: YES I AM WAITING FOR TIME :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

`SELECT * FROM  logedfeeds 
        WHERE ip LIKE '%127.0.0.1%' 
        GROUP BY user_id 
        ORDER BY  id
        DESC LIMIT 1000000`

Comment: And concatenate the variables inside the loop.